# How to retrieve a specific Column From Parse with swift?

Tags: swift, parse-platform, pfquery

I have a Array column in my parse Class called "serviceHistory". Its in JSON format. I am having trouble querying just this column for all my parse objects(pool Accounts).

With This code i can print out each object, but i am having trouble accessing just the service History column.

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"PoolAccount")
query.selectKeys(["serviceHistory"])
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

  if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {

    self.serviceHistory = objects
    print("these are the selectedKeys \(objects)")

   //THIS PRINTS THE WHOLE OBJECT, AND NOT JUST THE SELECTED KEY."serviceHistory"
```

[image]

I am looking to print out just the service History and can't find the right query to do it...Its an array of JSONS for Each Object.

[image]

this is what I'm looking for it to print out..Each Pfobject has an array of JSONs attached to it. So i think i possibly need an array of arrays to put it in? [[PFObject]]? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query will always return an array of `PFObject`, you can't limit to a single column only. You can post process the objects to extract an array containing only that column content for each object:

```
... = objects.valueForKey("selectedKeys")
```

Comment: I tried this(maybe the wrong way) but "valueForKey" is only working for 1 PFObject and not all the pfobjects in the array...how do i get all the pfobjects array of JSON into one array?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out..I used a for Loop and looped through each object and then used valueForKey and appended all the numbers to an array.

```
    for object in objects {

      if let dataObject:AnyObject = object.valueForKey("serviceHistory") {
      let thisJson = JSON(dataObject)

      for (_, entry) in thisJson {

        if let freeChlorineJson = entry["freeChlorine"].string {

          self.freeChlorine.append(freeChlorineJson)
          print(self.freeChlorine)
        }
```